# Jpos client ignores header specified in channel configuration file. What`s wrong?

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

Here is my client channel adaptor configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<channel-adaptor name="jpos-client-adaptor" class="org.jpos.q2.iso.OneShotChannelAdaptor" logger="Q2">
   <channel class="org.jpos.iso.channel.NACChannel" logger="Q2" packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.ISO87APackager" header="6000010152">
      <property name="host" value="localhost" />
      <property name="port" value="65000" />
      <!--        <property name="packager-config" value="${catalina.base}\\isoproperties\\iso8583ver87Packager.xml"/>-->
   </channel>
   <in>channel-Tx</in>
   <out>channel-Rx</out>
   <max-connections>1</max-connections>
   <max-connect-attempts>3</max-connect-attempts>
</channel-adaptor>
```

While debugging in ISORequestListener class expected header is not seen. Client and server are using the same packager.
[image: specified header not seen]

Also, the wrong MTI is seen while debugging.

sent:

> 0200

got:

> 23114

[image: got wrong MTI]

Comment: Are you setting the header at your ISOMsg level? 

You may want to add
 
`<property name='override-header' value='true' />`

to your channel configuration.